# Selenium python - spotify page

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to click a follow button on a spotify page with selenium but it wont work.
I've tried xpath and class_name but its not working.

The page im trying to click the follow button is [page](https://open.spotify.com/user/94ueka5j8y1jt466781y2frlp?si=rHBZSsT_TS2VHujyPKvMUw&utm_source=copy-link&nd=1)

**Html Elemant:**

```
<button type="button" class="aAr9nYtPsG7P2LRzciXc">Follow</button>
```

I think spotify randomizes the class names in order to prevent scrapping

**My Code:**

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section/div/div[3]/div/button[1]').click()
```

Comment: What element are you trying to access on what exactly page?

Comment: @Prophet its the "follow" button on this page => https://open.spotify.com/user/94ueka5j8y1jt466781y2frlp?si=rHBZSsT_TS2VHujyPKvMUw&utm_source=copy-link&nd=1

Comment: @PSR how did you guess that?

Comment: "<button type="button" class="aAr9nYtPsG7P2LRzciXc">Follow</button>", from this i understand its a button called "Follow", and OP has linked the site as well. @Prophet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are simply missing a delay.
The best way to do that is to use Expected Conditions explicit waits.
Also your locator can be improved.
With the following inports

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

After instantiating the `wait` object with

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
```

Your click action could be performed with:

```py
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Follow']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using XPATH, you can use cssSelector which is much simpler and direct

```
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class=aAr9nYtPsG7P2LRzciXc]")
button.click()
```

Edit: since everyone mentioned about waiting I added the implicit wait

Note: no, the driver wont wait 20 seconds but it will immediately execute after finding the element. 20 seconds is the maximum time you let it search for the button.

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>Follow</kbd> element is a ***dynamic*** element.

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-testid='action-bar-row'] > button:not(aria-label)"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Follow']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine.

but from my experience of "not getting an element from a page" the problem was that i didnt `wait enough` for the page to load.

try this:

```py
from time import sleep

sleep(0.5) # or 1 second if its slower to load
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section/div/div[3]/div/button[1]').click()
```

you dont have to wait 20 seconds, lol.

you just need some seconds before that element.